# How do I create a numbered list inside a quote?

Tags: lists, csquotes

I have a quote that I need to write like this:
     "1. first item,
      2. second item,
      3. third item." 
But I can only get the quotation marks to go inside the numbers like this:
     1."first item,
       2. second item,
       3. third item."
Any ideas how to solve this would be a big help!

Answer (score 3):

Without using a quoting environment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item [``\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.] first item
\item second item
\item third item''
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the occurrence were to be common, one could define in the preamble

```
\def\qitem{\item [``\stepcounter{enumi}\theenumi.]}
```

and then use it as

```
\qitem first item
```

inside the `enumerate` environment.